# Why does version 0.9.12 of jCrop produce a small black box in the upper left corner of selection area?

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I used the following script with jcrop and had no problems until I upgraded to version 0.9.12. Now, the selection area has a small black box in the upper left corner. When I make a selection, I am unable to grab the corners or sides to resize my selection. What do I need to do to make it work with the new version?

HTML:

```
<img id="cropbox" src="image/path" alt="image">
<form class="margin_top_10" action="my_file.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x">
    <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y">
    <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w">
    <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h">
    <input type="hidden" id="pic_to_crop" name="pic_to_crop" value="some value">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Crop Image">
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        onSelect: updateCoords, 
        setSelect:   [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ]
    });
});
function updateCoords(c)
{
    $('#x').val(c.x);
    $('#y').val(c.y);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
};
function checkCoords()
{
    if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
    return false;
};
</script>
```

[image]

I can click anywhere inside the selected are and drag the selection around the image, but as you can see, I am unable to stretch the selection area (unless I click and drag on the black box). Also, when I click and drag the little black box "up", then the selection area suddenly flips (i.e., it becomes rotated 180 degrees about the x-axis). This doesn't occur, however, if I click and drag the black box "down".

Comment: What browser(s) are you seeing this behavior in? Are there any JS errors being returned to the console?

Comment: Should have asked this before, which version of jQuery?

Comment: jQuery version 1.9. When I did the upgrade I noticed that jCrop didn't work anymore. The jCrop webpage indicated that I needed to upgrade to jCrop version 0.9.12. After the upgrades I was able to get jCrop to partially work, but with the gray box in the upper right corner, and without the ability to resize the selection area.

Comment: Any Chance you can create a http://jsfiddle.net/ that duplicates yoru issue? I can't get it to duplicate this problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? We're seeing it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue and it took me a while to figure out what was going on. In the 0.9.12 release, jcrop switched to using the .css file to define the placement of the handles for resizing instead of having them set in the .js file. Once I realized that, a quick check of my jquery.Jcrop.css file showed that it wasn't up to date. In particular, a section was missing that contains settings like this:

```
.jcrop-handle.ord-w {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  top: 50%;
}
```

There is an entry like this for every handle (n,e,s,w,ne,nw,se,sw) and without these, the position of all handles will default to 0,0. If you haven't already, I would suggest going here:

https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/tree/master/css

and grab the latest .css files to replace your existing ones. And of course, clear the cache before testing (which I forgot to do an cost myself another fruitless ten minutes).

Really hope this helps anyone else seeing this issue.